# ReactDom createPortal() doesn't work but render() does, and only once not if trigger is repeated - why is this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, carbon-design-system

Newbie to react here.

TLDR: I have a helper function called `createNotification` which when called inserts a `<ToastNotification />` component into a `container` element using render(). If I use createPortal() nothing is appended. If I use render, the component is only added once despite multiple triggers.

Can anyone help me figure out whats happening please?

Thank you

helpers.js

```
import { ToastNotification } from "carbon-components-react";
import { render, createPortal } from "react-dom";

export const createNotification = () => {
  const container = document.getElementById("notificationContainer");
  console.log(container); //just to check function is running and has found container
  return render(<ToastNotification />, container); //works but only once, not on multiple triggers
  return createPortal(<ToastNotification />, container); //doesn't render anything in container
};
```

the function above is called from other components as needed:

login.js

```
import { createNotification } from "../../helpers";

const Login = () => {
  const validateLogin = async (event) => {
    createNotification();
    // validation logic
    performLogin();
  };

  const performLogin = async () => {
    //axios call here
  };

  // main component content
  return (
    <>
     <!-- validateLogin() called on form submit -->
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

app.js

```
//imports

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Thank you

Comment: did you render createNotification  or whole app by render funtion ?

Comment: app.js was return() and createNotification() is called in the Login() component (code added above)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved this myself by adding the `createPortal()` within the `render()`.

If anyone can provide an explanation, it would be much appreciated.

```
export const createNotification = () => {
  const container = document.getElementById("notificationContainer");
  console.log(container);
  return render(createPortal(<ToastNotification />, container), document.createElement("div"));
};
```

Comment: Hey, did you figure out a way to do it without `render` method? ... Looks like it's gonna be deprecated soon.

Comment: @kcsujeet sorry no, that project is no long mine to maintain. Currently though I use the toast component from radix: https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/toast

Answer (score 0):

createNotification aren't mounted in component in app Virtual Dom... when you use render(createPortal) then you just create spearted app.

```
import { createNotification } from "../../helpers";

export const createNotification = () => {
    const container = document.getElementById("notificationContainer");
    console.log(container); //just to check function is running and has found container
    return createPortal(<ToastNotification />, container); //doesn't render anything in container
};

const Login = () => {
    const [validate, setValidate] = useState(false);
    
    const validateLogin = async (event) => {
        if('some logic')
            return setValidte(true)
        setVAlidte(false)
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        if(!valite)
            return;
        //axios heare
    }, [validate])
    // main component content
    
    
    return (
        <>
            {!validate && <CreateNotfication/>}
            <!-- validateLogin() called on form submit -->
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert , what advantages/pros does this method have over my attempt (see other answer)? Thank you.

Comment: you mount it under app three. not as separate app. so you is treated as one whole app with some portal. This is just correct way. ["Just read the instruction".](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) if you done it by wrap it by render then you lose event bubling....